# pytest mock function but verify parameters

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-mock

I have a method with an external API call.

The external API call that takes two parameters (a XML string and number) and if it is successful it creates something in the external system.

```
def create_stuff(my_number: int,name: str):
    try:
        new_value = my_number + 5
        stuff_xml = '''<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
        <description>''' + name + '''</description>
        <properties/>'''
        external_api_call.create_stuff(name, new_value)
        return {"status": 'success', "message": "created stuff '" + name}
    except Exception as e:
        return {"status": 'failure', "message": "error while creating stuff: " + str(e)}
```

Because I can't reach the external system from the pytest environment and really don't want to create something there just for testing purposes, I decided to mock the external call.

```
def test_create_stuff(mocker):
    mocker.patch(
        'path.to.class.external_api_call.create_stuff',
        return_value=5
    )

    assert actual['status'] == 'success'
```

In the function the external call handles the verification of the parameters (i.e. is the XML structure valid), but if I mock the external call I can't validate if the rest of the function works as designed.

Is there a way to grab the parameters of the external call and validate them?

For example like this:

```
def test_create_folder_success(credentials_valid,status_succeded, jenkins_extension_mocked):
    my_mocker = mocker.patch(
        'path.to.class.external_api_call.create_stuff',
        return_value=5
    )
    actual  = my_class.create_stuff(my_number=5,name="foo")
    xml = xml.etree.ElementTree.parse(my_mocker.name) 
    value = my_mocker.new_value
    assert actual['status'] == 'success'
    assert value == 10
    assert validate_xml(xml) == True
```

Comment: Why not just access the call arguments from the mock, then you can assert whatever you want on them?

Comment: do you have an example? I think that's basically what I want to achieve.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.mock_calls

Answer (score 2):

thank you jonrsharpe and sry for the late response!
with your help I was able to get it woking:

```
def test_create_folder_success(credentials_valid,status_succeded):
    with mock.patch('path.to.class.external_api_call.create_stuff')  as my_mocker:
        actual  = my_class.create_stuff(my_number=5,name="foo")
        my_args = my_mocker.call_args
        xml = xml.etree.ElementTree.parse(my_args[1])
        assert validate_xml(xml) == True
        value = my_mocker.new_value
        assert actual['status'] == 'success'
        assert value == 10
```